# ImageSpan with EmojiCompat

Tags: android, androidx, imagespan

I am using Android X emoji2 EmojiCompat and when I set an `ImageSpan` over some text containing an emoji, it ends up getting split by the `EmojiSpan` and showing two images, one on each side of the emoji in the middle, instead of one image and no emoji.

Is there a workaround for this?  I don't want to disable EmojiCompat on the text box completely for when people enter other emoji, but I want my ImageSpan to not be disrupted by it...